# JSONException when trying to parse the result of an HttpResponse

Tags: android, json

[The json in json lint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3qiQ.jpg)
Every similar response to this I've found has somebody incorrectly using a JSONArray. I'm using JSONObject.

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
String json_string = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

updateBoundaries(new JSONObject(json_string));
System.out.println(json_string);
```

Gets me the error

> org.json.JSONException: Value {"TopLeftCorner":{"Longitude":0.0,"Latitude":100.0},"TopRightCorner":{"Longitude":100.0,"Latitude":100.0},"BottomLeftCorner":{"Longitude":0.0,"Latitude":0.0},"BottomRightCorner":{"Longitude":100.0,"Latitude":0.0}} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

However, when I copy paste the JSON into JSON Lint, it's perfectly fine. When I print out the string it's trying to parse, it looks like

> "{\"TopLeftCorner\":{\"Longitude\":0.0,\"Latitude\":100.0},\"TopRightCorner\":{\"Longitude\":100.0,\"Latitude\":100.0},\"BottomLeftCorner\":{\"Longitude\":0.0,\"Latitude\":0.0},\"BottomRightCorner\":{\"Longitude\":100.0,\"Latitude\":0.0}}"

It looks like it should be acceptable JSON, but JSONObject can't parse it for some reason. What's going on?

Edit: stacktrace

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"TopLeftCorner":{"Longitude":0.0,"Latitude":100.0},"TopRightCorner":{"Longitude":100.0,"Latitude":100.0},"BottomLeftCorner":{"Longitude":0.0,"Latitude":0.0},"BottomRightCorner":{"Longitude":100.0,"Latitude":0.0}} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)

W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)

W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)

W/System.err:     at com.example.chan.locationapiapp.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:62)

W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: You `toString()`'d an already valid JSON string.

Comment: Also note: Apache HTTP is deprecated on Android. Volley can make JSON requests. https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html#request-json

Comment: Thanks! I'll try using that instead. I'm sick of dealing with JSON errors-if Volly can do it for me that'd be a lot better.

Comment: Yeah, while the first JSON looks correct, `System.out.println` shouldn't be the way to Log on android. Use the `Log.d()` method instead. And I would put `new JSONObject(json_string)` into a separate variable that you can later parse or just make `updateBoundaries` take the string object.

Comment: The error is coming from the call to `new JSONObject(json_string)` so I'm thinking that this may be an encoding issue. I'd really rather not have to do manual string manipulation, but that's my last resort if JSON keeps failing. I'll keep at it.

Comment: Please [edit] your post with the full stacktrace

Comment: Thanks, can you post the URL so that we can check it for the JSON response ourselves?

Comment: It's a program I'm running out of Visual Studio 2015. I don't think you'd be able to connect if you're not on the network. I wish I could give you more information. I'll edit the post to include an image of the json in json lint though.

Comment: Yes, the JSON seems valid, so go ahead and try the Volley approach (you'll need to add a dependency for it).

Comment: I figured out that the problem had to do with the server and not what I was using to parse the JSON. Thanks for taking the time to help me. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the server I was hitting was producing an extra pair of quotes around the string (""STRING"") and I had to replace all of the backslashes \ with empty characters, and then it was able to parse.